# Yii ActiveRecord model save by chain

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, chaining

There is a model:

```php
class Model extends ActiveRecord
{
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__) {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    public function toSave(Array $data)
    {
        $this->setAttributes($data);
        $this->save(); // returns true
        return $this;
    }
}
```

and running

```php
$model = Model::model()->toSave($data);
```

and when im dumping $model there is all data which setted from $data but not exists PrimaryKey (id).

but, if i run

```php
$model = new Model;
$model->toSave($data);
```

works as expected.

Where is a problem?

Answer (score 0):

you are doing multiple save, through iterating, and pass new set of  `$data` everytime. `$model` here is an object of single record. So by doing everytime, new model , you are creating fresh new object, assign data and save. Later you did is the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

You usage in invalid in the first instance

```
$model = Model::model()->toSave($data);
```

In this case, the usage is calling the toSave() method **statically**.

First, the usage is illegal unless you change your declaration

```
public static  function toSave(Array $data) { ... }
```

In addition, when invoked statically, the value for $this is invalid.

Therefore, the valid usage is your second version:

```
$model = new Model;
$model->toSave($data);
```

References:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php